# Datatable editor Fatal error Uncaught Error: Call to a member function transaction() on string

Tags: php, mysql, datatable

I am trying to make inline editor datatable but getting error. I have downloaded trial of php datatable editor. I am not getting the problem if anyone could find it it will be very much help.

```
 Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function transaction() on 
 string in Editor.php:547 Stack trace: #0editor_datatable.php(40) : 
 DataTables\Editor->process(Array) #1 {main} thrown in Editor.php on 
 line 547
```

My PHP File is

```
<?php
// DataTables PHP library
include( "Editor/php/DataTables.php" );


// Alias Editor classes so they are easy to use
use
DataTables\Editor,
DataTables\Editor\Field,
DataTables\Editor\Format,
DataTables\Editor\Mjoin,
DataTables\Editor\Upload,
DataTables\Editor\Validate;

// Build our Editor instance and process the data coming from _POST
Editor::inst( 'metro_rail', 'bim_with_vault_final_master_data' , 'id')
->fields(
    Field::inst( 'Document_Number' )->validator( 'Validate::notEmpty' ),
    Field::inst( 'Revision' )->validator( 'Validate::notEmpty' ),
    Field::inst( 'Title' )->validator( 'Validate::notEmpty' ),
    Field::inst( 'Revision_Date' )->validator( 'Validate::notEmpty' ),
    Field::inst( 'Design_Stage' )->validator( 'Validate::notEmpty' ),
    Field::inst( 'Status' )->validator( 'Validate::notEmpty' ),
    Field::inst( 'File_Type' )->validator( 'Validate::notEmpty' ),
    Field::inst( 'Upload_Date' )->validator( 'Validate::notEmpty' ),
    Field::inst( 'Source' )->validator( 'Validate::notEmpty' ),
    Field::inst( 'REV_CHK' )->validator( 'Validate::notEmpty' ),
    Field::inst( 'DESIGN_STAGE_CHANGED' )->validator( 
'Validate::notEmpty' ),
    Field::inst( 'STATUS_CHANGED' )->validator( 'Validate::notEmpty' ),
    Field::inst( 'Model_Status' )->validator( 'Validate::notEmpty' ),
    Field::inst( 'Model_Captured_Status' )->validator( 
'Validate::notEmpty' ),
    Field::inst( 'PROJECT_DES' )->validator( 'Validate::notEmpty' ),
    Field::inst( 'ORG_DES' )->validator( 'Validate::notEmpty' ),
    Field::inst( 'DIS_DES' )->validator( 'Validate::notEmpty' ),
    Field::inst( 'TECH_DIS_DES' )->validator( 'Validate::notEmpty' ),
    Field::inst( 'SUB_SYS_DES' )->validator( 'Validate::notEmpty' ),
    Field::inst( 'DOC_TYPE_DES' )->validator( 'Validate::notEmpty' ),
    Field::inst( 'WBS_DES' )->validator( 'Validate::notEmpty' )
)
->process( $_POST )
->json();
?>
```

What is the problem?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cant say anything about datatable editor but as fas as I can see your error it says that where you are calling a function named transaction must be like $obj->transaction()  but in your case $obj is not the object its a string